# Extracting the saved local variables of the generator data structure of Future

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

From the "Rust for Rustaceans" book, I read that "... every await or yield is really a return from the function. After all, there are several local variables in the function, and it’s not clear how they’re restored when we resume later on. This is where the **compiler-generated part of generators** comes into play. The compiler transparently injects code to **persist those variables into and read them from the generator’s associated data structure, rather than the stack**, at the time of execution. So if you declare, write to, or read from some local variable a, you are really operating on something akin to self.a"

Say I have something like this:

```
use futures::future::{AbortHandle, Abortable};
use tokio::{time::sleep};
use std::{time::Duration};

async fn echo(s: String, times_to_repeat: u32) {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    for n in 0..times_to_repeat {
        println!("Iteration {} Echoing {}", n, s.clone());
        vec.push(s.clone());
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(10)).await;
    }
}

 
async fn child(s: String) {
    echo(s, 100).await
}
 
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (abort_handle, abort_registration) = AbortHandle::new_pair();
    let result_fut = Abortable::new(child(String::from("Hello")), abort_registration);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        abort_handle.abort();
    });

    result_fut.await.unwrap();
}
```

After abort has been called, how do I save/ serialize variables like `n` and `vec`? Is there a way to reach within the inside of the data structure of the generator that is generated from Future?

Comment: Even if that were possible it would be prone to data races. Perhaps consider storing the data outside of the function, and referencing it from inside the function? Either way you'll need to be careful to avoid deadlock if your future is in the middle of doing something when you abort it; for example if you're in the middle of writing some data, it will permanently hold that lock. Maybe it would help  to understand your larger use case?

Comment: There is no sound way to do that. If you only want to do that to understand how the compiler works, then this is possible.